# TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to apply transfer learning to the InceptionV3. Here is my code:

```
inception_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
output_inception = inception_model.output
output_globalavgpooling = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(output_inception)
output_dense = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(output_globalavgpooling)
predictions = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(output_dense)

final_model = Model(inception_model.input,output=predictions)

final_model.compile()

inception_model.summary()
```

When I run this code I am getting following error at the `final_model = Model(inception_model.input,output=predictions)` line:

```
TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.
```

What should I do?

Comment: in Model() , output argument is wrong just add "s".
it's outputs.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error. In my case it was due to using an old version of Keras and Tensorflow 2 from conda. There currently is some issues preventing the use of Tensorflow 2 with current Keras via conda.

I created a new environment and installed using according to the Keras/Tensorflow websites (CPU only version in my case):

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

Comment: This solution works for CPU only versions. But not for GPU enabled versions

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
final_model = tf.compat.v1.keras.Model(inception_model.input,output=predictions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to magiclantern answer, if you are using GPU then you can use the following commands.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu 
pip install keras-gpu
```

Or if you want to use certain versions then use the following commands

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
pip install keras-gpu==2.3.1
```

This should work fine.