# TypeError("Tensor is unhashable) while working with Tensorflow, Keras, and Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I am having an issue with some simple Yolo detection code I am porting to tensorflow 2. The code is somewhat straight forward but I am having an issue with learning phase "tf.keras.learning_phase(): 0 ". This generates the err0r

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam_detect.py", line 188, in <module>
    r_image, ObjectsList = yolo.detect_image(frame)
  File "webcam_detect.py", line 110, in detect_image
    K.learning_phase(): 0
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\simplecv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 705, in __hash__
    raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. "
TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.
(simplecv) PS C:\dev\lacv\yolov3\yolov3ct>
```

here is a code snippet although I have posted the full file on gist

```
    def detect_image(self, image):
        if self.model_image_size != (None, None):
            assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            boxed_image = image_preporcess(np.copy(image), tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
            image_data = boxed_image

        out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
            [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
            feed_dict={
                self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
                self.input_image_shape: [image.shape[0], image.shape[1]],
                tf.keras.learning_phase(): 0  })
```

complete code is here https://gist.github.com/robisen1/31976de17af9e752c6ba8d1dd0e08906

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778872/typeerror-tensor-is-unhashable-if-tensor-equality-is-enabled-instead-use-tens) help?

Comment: No but thank you. I am almost totally sure know it is due to third party libraries not being up to date. I am going to try downgrading TF to 1.15 and see